# Android Scale a bitmap image

Tags: android, canvas, matrix, image-manipulation, scale

My application has 9 bitmap images on it in a 3x3 grid. All of them are showing on the screen and depending on how the user interacts with them (tap, double tap, pinch, zoom, drag) the image that is "action-ed on" needs to perform different tasks.

So for example, if I tap on one image, it needs to rotate around the it's vertical access completely, then stop.

Currently i'm using SurfaceView with the onTouchEvent(..) method. The way I figured I could animate this is by scaling the image's width from 1 to -1 back to 1. I've been trying to use a matrix, but I can't get the image to stay centered in it's spot. Please help me fix this or suggest an alternate/better way of accomplishing this.

My current code is just a test. If ***b*** is true, then the method will attempt to scale the bitmap. If ***b*** is false then it will draw the bitmap normally.:

```
public void doDraw(Canvas canvas, boolean b)
{
    Matrix m = new Matrix();

    float scale = .5f;
    m.setScale(scale, 1f);
    m.postTranslate(mX,mY);

    if(!b)
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mX, mY, null);
    else
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, m, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of `postTranslate`

```
matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);
```

where centerX,Y is the center of the bitmap

**UPDATE**

you can play with graphics.camera on android that transforms the matrix. Access the camera to the main view(the grid) and override getChildStaticTransformation. Get the transformation matrix. `t.getMatrix()` and alter that one. You can move it anywhere you want **since this is the matrix from the main view** but is addressed only to render that particular child.

so do something like that

```
@Override
    protected boolean getChildStaticTransformation(View child, Transformation t) {
        Matrix matrix = t.getMatrix();
            int centerX = (child.getWidth() / 2);
            int centerY = (child.getHeight() / 2);
        t.clear();
        t.setTransformationType(Transformation.TYPE_MATRIX);
        mCamera.save();

        if (child == getChildAt(0)) {
            mCamera.translate(pixels to the right,pixels to the bottom,
                    to the z axis);
            mCamera.getMatrix(matrix);
            mCamera.restore();
            matrix.preTranslate(-centerX, -centerY);
            matrix.postTranslate(centerX, centerY);

        } 

        return true;
    }
```

Also dont forget to set `setStaticTransformationsEnabled(true)`; somewhere to the constructor of the grid

Comment: I'm assuming you mean like this:
`float scale = -1f;
     m.preTranslate(-mX, -mY);
     m.setScale(scale, 1f);
     m.postTranslate(mX,mY);`
But that didn't work. I also tried the order scale, pretranslate, posttranslate. Nothing

Comment: It keeps the image lined against the left edge. I need it to be centered.

Comment: The problem with this is that my images aren't `View` 's (which is what it looks like you're treating them as) but instead are `Bitmap`s. I only have on `View` in the whole program right now, `SurfaceView`. On top of that I need to have a way to do scaling, rotating, and dragging of images. Correct me if I'm wrong, but this doesn't seem like the best way of getting prepared for that kind of manipulation.

Comment: No this applies to ImageViews or in general android View

Comment: Right... so I appreciate the answer, but it isn't helpful given my specific situation.

Comment: I apologize for the late response to this. I should have just worked with ImageViews like you implied.