# Cropping , Scaling and Rotating image in Android

Tags: android

I would like to know how can I crop , scale and rotate a ImageView that have a scaled background image using a fixed width and height on it's parent.

Comment: [rotate-scale](http://blahti.wordpress.com/2014/02/03/android-rotate-scale-bitmap/) example , and after playing with that try and learn [this](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) important article from developer.android

Answer (score 1):

To crop (get subImage) see the following thread:

[How to Cut a ImageView to a subimage in the range of four specified points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841395/how-to-cut-a-imageview-to-a-subimage-in-the-range-of-four-specified-points)

For scale and rotate use Matrix with setScale and setRotate.

This forum has a number of threads discussing relevant topic, e.g.

[Android Scale a bitmap image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276574/android-scale-a-bitmap-image)

[Android - Rotate image around center point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491579/android-rotate-image-around-center-point)

Before publishing a question you better look around :)